# Generic type func-eval using ICorDebugEval

Tags: c#, generics, clr, cil, imetadataimport

I'm making a managed .NET debugger using MDBG sample.

MDBG has no support for property getters evaluation, which I'm trying to add. Please, consider following class structure:

```
    public abstract class Base<T>{
        public string SomeProp {get;set;}
    }

    public class A : Base<int>{

    }
```

At some point of time I'm creating an instance of A and stopping at a breakpoint to evaluate it's state.

In my debugger's watch window I introduce "this.SomeProp", that should perform a func-eval of get_SomeProp method on this object and return a null value for given case.

The first issue I've encountered was the fact, that get_SomeProp was defined on the base class, so I had to run through all TypeDefs/TypeRefs/TypeSpecs in the class hierarchy to find the function.

But after it was found, calling

```
   ICorDebugEval.CallFunction(function.CorFunction, new[] {@object.CorValue});
```

resulted in: *TypeLoadException: The generic type was used with the wrong number of generic arguments in assembly*.

As I've realized it happens because non-generic function is defined in a generic class (Base), so when I'm evaluating it I should also indicate class's generic params.

This could be done using

```
  ICorDebugEval2.CallParameterizedFunction(function.CorFunction,
    genericArguments,
    functionArguments);
```

**The problem is that I have no idea how to extract types of class generic parameters, having only function that I want to evaluate and instance on which I want to evaluate it.**

Here is some code I'm currently using:

```
    private MDbgValue EvaluatePropertyGetter(MDbgFrame scope, MDbgValue @object, string propertyName) {
        var propertyGetter = $"get_{propertyName}";
        var function = ResolveFunctionName(
            scope.Function.Module.CorModule.Name,
            @object.TypeName,
            propertyGetter,
            scope.Thread.CorThread.AppDomain);

        if (function == null) {
            throw new MDbgValueException("Function '" + propertyGetter + "' not found.");
        }

        var eval = Threads.Active.CorThread.CreateEval();
        var typeToken = function.CorFunction.Class.Token;
        var type = function.Module.Importer.GetType(typeToken); //checked that type containing function is generic
        if (type.IsGenericType) {
            //------------->need to get class'es generic param types<------------
            var genericType1 = this.ResolveType("System.Object"); // just a stub
            eval.CallParameterizedFunction(function.CorFunction, new CorType[] {genericType1}, new[] {@object.CorValue});
        }
        else {
            eval.CallFunction(function.CorFunction, new[] {@object.CorValue});
        }

        Go().WaitOne();
        if (!(StopReason is EvalCompleteStopReason)) {
            // we could have received also EvalExceptionStopReason but it's derived from EvalCompleteStopReason
            Console.WriteLine("Func-eval not fully completed and debuggee has stopped");
            Console.WriteLine("Result of funceval won't be printed when finished.");
        }
        else {
            eval = (StopReason as EvalCompleteStopReason).Eval;
            Debug.Assert(eval != null);

            var cv = eval.Result;
            if (cv != null) {
                var mv = new MDbgValue(this, cv);
                return mv;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any suggestion/advice is greatly appreciated!

Regards,

---

**Solution**

Thanks to @Brian Reichle outstanding answer I came up with this solution:

```
 if (type.IsGenericType) {
            //getting Type's Generic parameters
            var typeParams = GetGenericArgs(@object.CorValue.ExactType, function.CorFunction.Class.Token);
            eval.CallParameterizedFunction(function.CorFunction, typeParams.ToArray(), new[] {@object.CorValue});
        }
```

And the function itself:

```
 private List<CorType> GetGenericArgs(CorType corType, int classTk) {
        if (corType == null)
            return null;
        List<CorType> list = new List<CorType>();

        var param =corType.TypeParameters;
        var args = GetGenericArgs(corType.Base, classTk);

        if (classTk == corType.Class.Token) {
            list.AddRange(param.Cast<CorType>());
        }

        if (args != null) {
            list.AddRange(args);}

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ICorDebugValue2::GetExactType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231644(v=vs.110).aspx) on the value object representing an instance of `A` to get the ICorDebugType for type `A`, [ICorDebugType::GetBase()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233297(v=vs.110).aspx) to get its base class (`Base<int>`) and [ICorDebugType::EnumerateTypeParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230283(v=vs.110).aspx) on the base type to get it's type arguments.

Comment: Thank you again, Brian, for helping me out! Unfortunately using GetExactType returns closed type A, and EnumerateTypeParameters returns 0 params, since this type has no generic parameters. I guess I have to get Base<int> somehow to use EnumerateTypeParams. Should I go down the inheritance hierarchy to get that type or I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the call to GetBase() :)

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried with GetBase and it' works for a simple scenario that I've have in the question. Currently I'm trying out a more complicated scenario with A : B<int,string>, while B<T,T1> : C<T>.  In this case I'm navigating to B<T,T1> and getting it's generic params. But the result of evaluation in this case is **TargetParameterCountException** :Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.

Comment: It sounds like you might be calling a method on `C<>` with the type arguments from `B<,>`.

Comment: In fact it's the case! I'm getting **first** generic type definition from the hierarchy. So going from A to B<int,string> I'm stopping, but in fact the function that I'm calling is defined in C<T>. But how should I understand which class's generic parameters to take?

Comment: Use the type arguments from whichever level defined the method. (This would probably be easier if you use GetBase to walk up the hierarchy instead of trying to calculate it from IMetaDataImport :)).